# Extend a Java Enum with additional functions

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum from a common Library (it cannot be changed) as a field from a Class.

I need to use that enum values as a switch-case in order to do something accordingly (for example save some data to a database).

This is for a Java 11 micro-service using Spring as a framework. 
What I did before knowing the enum has to stay immutable, I avoided an ugly switch case with an overridden abstract function inside the enum like this:

```java
public enum InvoiceStatus {

  DRAFT {
    @Override public void action(InputMessage inputMessage) {
      invoiceFileService.draft(inputMessage);
    }
  },
  VALID {
    @Override public void action(InputMessage inputMessage) {
      invoiceFileService.valid(eiInvoiceFileMessage);
    }
  },
  NOT_VALID {
    @Override public void action(InputMessage inputMessage) {
      invoiceFileService.notValid(eiInvoiceFileMessage);
    }
  };
  //+20 more values...

  @Autowired
  InvoiceFileService invoiceFileService;


  public abstract void action(InputMessage inputMessage);

}
```

and I simply called the enum like this, so with different values from the enum the called function from the service would be different without writing a long switch-case.

```java
invoice.getStatus().action(inputMessage);
```

Now the new requirement needs the enum to live inside a common library so it can refer to InvoiceFileService class which will be only local to my project.

I tried different options like HashMaps but the code went ugly and un-maintainable.

Is there a clean way to extend the simple enum (with only values definition) and add to it the abstract function to do stuff? maybe java 8 added some new way to do this.

Comment: _Now the new requirement needs the enum to live inside a common library so it can refer to InvoiceFileService class which will be only local to my project._  Can you clarify what this means?  How would that even compile?

Comment: Could you describe what went ugly and unmaintainable?

Comment: Usually InvoiceFileService uses/called `InvoiceStatus`. What actually `InvoiceStatus` does?

Comment: @AndrewS sorry for my english: I mean the InvoiceStatus enum is an Import from an external library (common to other projects) so I can't add to it any additional behavior. InvoiceFileService can be whatever I want as it won't be used by any other project

Comment: @MichielLeegwater it would an object from EnumMap<InvoiceStatus, Supplier<Void>> class

Comment: @VenturiEffect since InvoiceStatus is from another jar, you could add new behaviour by using Adapter/Wrapper class. Example is in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a wrapper enum.

```java
public enum WrappedInvoiceStatus {
    DRAFT(InvoiceStatus.DRAFT, this::someAction),
    // other values 

    private WrappedInvoiceStatus(InvoiceStatus status, Action action) {
        this.status = status;
        this.action = action;
    }

    private interface Action { // can be one of Java default functional interfaces as well
        void doSomething(InputMessage msg);
    }

    private void someAction(InputMessage msg) {
        // behavior 
    }

    // some plumbing required 
}
```

Basically I’m suggesting using wrapping and lambda expressions or method references. The world of functional programming takes some getting used to. Not everyone is a fan. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

`Enum` type is not extendable and implicitly final as specified in JLS:-

> An enum declaration is implicitly final unless it contains at least one enum constant that has a class body (§8.9.1).

Hence a class could not `extends` an `enum` type. However you could use wrapper or adapter pattern to add additional behaviours/fields of the `enum`. For example:-

```
@Service
public class SimpleInvoiceFileService implements InvoiceFileService{

   private final InvoiceStatus invoiceStatus;

   public SimpleInvoiceFileService(InvoiceStatus status){

       invoiceStatus = status;
   }

   @Override
   public void draft(InputMessage input){
       this.invoiceStatus.action(input);
   }


   @Override
   public void valid(InputMessage input){
       this.invoiceStatus.action(input);
   }

   // Add more methods to InvoiceFileService interface 
   // as required and override them here.
}
```

JLS Reference:-
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9

Answer (score 0):

As others already said, you can not extend the enum at runtime.

But an enum can implement an interface.
So the basic idea is:

- You make an interface with the action as sole abstract method:

  ```
  public interface InvoiceAction {
      void action(InputMessage message);
  }
  ```
- Your enum implements that interface

  ```
  public enum InvoiceStatus implements InvoiceAction {
  // ... no other changes needed
  }
  ```
- In all the cases where you only need to use the actual action, change `InvoiceStatus` to `InvoiceAction`. This is the most risky change. Make sure to recompile all code.
- Because `InvoiceAction` only has one abstract method, it's a functional interface, and can be implemented with a lambda expression:

  ```
  invoice.setStatus(msg -> ...);
  ```

This change is probably the most invasive change, but it might be the right thing to do - if you need a different action next time, you won't have the same problem as today.